# AsymptoticDSolveValue returing input

Tags: asymptotics

I would like to find a uniform approximation of the solution to the boundary layer problem
$$\epsilon y'' + (x+x^3)y'-2y=0, \hspace{20mm}y(1)=y(-1)=1$$

When using AsymptoticDSolveValue, I inputted the following:

```
    0, y[-1] == 1, y[1] == 1}, y[x], x, {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}]
```

However, it just returned my statement. It refuses to solve specifically this problem: if I get rid of the $x^3$ term, it works, and similarly if I get rid of the $x$ term. How can I get it to solve the problem for me?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete code that you used.

Comment: @RonShvartsman Your ode only has symmetric solutions, that's why your bc `y[-1] == 1, y[1] == 1` aren't sufficient. Change to `y'[0] == 0, y[1] == 1`  and evaluation works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ode

```
ode = eps y''[x] + (x + x^3)*y'[x] - 2*y[x] == 0
ode /. y->(y[-#]&)
(* -2 y[-x] - (x + x^3) Derivative[1][y][-x] +eps (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[-x] == 0*)
```

only has symmetric solutions! That's why the bc `y[-1] == 1, y[1] == 1` aren't sufficient.

Change  bc to  `y'[0] == 0, y[1] == 1` and try

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ode, y'[0] == 0, y[1] == 1}, y, {x, -1, 1}, {eps}];
Plot[Table[sol[eps][x], {eps, {1, .1, .01, .001}}] , {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: hi, You think then Maple solution is not valid? Maple solves the BVP and verifies the solution: `ode :=  diff(y(x),x$2)+ (x + x^3)*diff(y(x),x) - 2*y(x) = 0;
ic:=y(1)=1,y(-1)=1; sol:=dsolve([ode,ic]);` gives `[0,0,0]` which means the solution both BC are verified. Screen shot   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLoW4.png) I am just trying to understand when you say that both conditions are not enough, but then how did Maple solve it?  Or did you mean this is specific to Asymptotic expansion only?

Comment: @Nasser I observed that MMA-solution `ParametricNDSolve` doesn't fullfill bc `y[-1] == 1, y[1] == 1`for `eps<.01`(you showed it too in your answer/Manipulate-example). Maple solution is valid I think, if solution tends to `(2 x^2)/(1 + x^2) , eps->0`

Comment: A typo. The `ReplaceAll` should be  `ode /. y -> (y[-#] &)`

Comment: @cvgmt Thanks for your hint, I corrected my answer

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica can not do it. May be because it is boundary value problem. Compare

```
ode = y''[x] + (x + x^3)*y'[x] - 2*y[x] == 0;
ic = {y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0};
AsymptoticDSolveValue[{ode, ic}, y[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now change the ic to

```
ode = y''[x] + (x + x^3)*y'[x] - 2*y[x] == 0;
ic = {y[-1] == 1, y[1] == 1};
AsymptoticDSolveValue[{ode, ic}, y[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So no point of trying the perturbation problem if it can't solve the asymptotic one.

Mathematica also can't solve this analytically (with or without $\epsilon$)

```
ode = y''[x] + (x + x^3)*y'[x] - 2*y[x] == 0;
ic = {y[-1] == 1, y[1] == 1};
DSolveValue[{ode, ic}, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So your best hope is to try numerical solution and manually adjust $\epsilon$ and look at the solution. Something like

```
ode = eps*y''[x] + (x + x^3)*y'[x] - 2*y[x] == 0;
ic = {y[-1] == 1, y[1] == 1};
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ode, ic}, y, {x, -1, 1}, {eps}];
Manipulate[
 Plot[sol[eps][x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1, 1}}],
 {{eps, .01, "eps"}, 0.01, .1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 ContinuousAction -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {eps}
 ]
```

[image]

The analytical solution is given by Maple in terms of Heun special functions which I do not think Mathematica currently supports. *Correction*: Thanks to comment, these special function are now in [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/HeunAndRelatedFunctions.html).

```
ode := epsilon* diff(y(x),x$2)+ (x + x^3)*diff(y(x),x) - 2*y(x) = 0;
sol:=dsolve([ode,y(1)=1,y(-1)=1])
```

[image]

```
y(x) = 1/HeunB(-1/2,1/epsilon^(1/2),-3/2,5/2/epsilon^(1/2),1/2/epsilon^(1/2))*
exp(-1/4*(x-1)*(x+1)*(x^2+3)/epsilon)*HeunB(-1/2,1/epsilon^(1/2),-3/2,5/2/
epsilon^(1/2),1/2/epsilon^(1/2)*x^2)
```

But Maple could not take the series of the above or figure the limit either. Maple does not have `AsymptoticDSolveValue` like command either. Here is plot of the analytical solution for small value of $\epsilon$

```
plot(eval(rhs(sol),epsilon=0.001),x=-2..2)
```

[image]

When trying for smaller $\epsilon$ in Maple I get

```
plot(eval(rhs(sol),epsilon=0.00001),x=-2..2)
Warning, breaking the computation of HeunB after 20000 terms, the series is not converging
```

[image]

And for #\epsilon=1$

```
   plot(eval(rhs(sol),epsilon=1),x=-2..2)
```

[image]

WHich agrees with what numerical solution by `NDSolve` shows as $\epsilon$ gets larger.

So it seems your problem is pushing the envelope of what Mathematica can do at this time.

Comment: Maybe I am misinterpreting your comment, however, looks like MMA supports these: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/HeunAndRelatedFunctions.html

Comment: @Moo these must be added in newer version. Last time I checked (may be one year ago or so, these special functions did not exist). Good to know they have been added.